# ElasticSearch: Aggregation to get property values from object-in-array that is in an object which is in array

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, filter, facet, elasticsearch-aggregation

> ##### GOAL: Get the `values` associated with the `characteristic` named `"ram"`

---

#### Example Object/Schema:

###### Showcase Path: `product{}.characteristics[].values[]`

```
    Product {
      "characteristics": [  //1st level      
        { //1st level object
          "name": "ram",
          "values": [ //2nd level
            {"value": 2}, //to be returned in aggregation
            {"value": 4} //to be returned in aggregation
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Document:

```json
{
        "_index": "product",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "18",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "id": 18,
            "name": "iphone_11",
            "localizedName": [
              {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "value": "iPhone 11"
              }
            ],
            "productType": null,
            "shops": [
              
            ],
            "characteristics": [
              {
                "name": "ram",
                "values": [
                  {
                    "value": "2",
                    "localizedValues": [
                      
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value": "4",
                    "localizedValues": [
                      
                    ]
                  }
                ],
                "localizedName": [
                  {
                    "id": 15,
                    "locale": "en-US",
                    "value": "Ram"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
```

Mappings:

```
    {
        "product": {
            "mappings": {
                "properties": {
                    "doc": {
                        "properties": {
                            "characteristics": {
                                "type": "nested",
                                "properties": {
                                    "localizedName": {
                                        "properties": {
                                            "id": {
                                                "type": "long"
                                            },
                                            "locale": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "name": {
                                        "type": "text",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "keyword": {
                                                "type": "keyword",
                                                "ignore_above": 256
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "values": {
                                        "type": "nested",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "value": {
                                                "type": "text",
                                                "fields": {
                                                    "keyword": {
                                                        "type": "keyword",
                                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            "id": {
                                "type": "long"
                            },
                            "name": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Current aggregation traversal:

```json
    {
      "size": 0,
      "aggs": {
        "characteristics": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "characteristics"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "ram": {
              "filter": {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "characteristics.name": "ram"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "values": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "characteristics.values"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "all_values": {
                      "terms": {
                        "field": "characteristics.values.value"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Response:

```
    {
        "took": 2,
        "timed_out": false,
        "_shards": {
            "total": 1,
            "successful": 1,
            "skipped": 0,
            "failed": 0
        },
        "hits": {
            "total": {
                "value": 0,
                "relation": "eq"
            },
            "max_score": null,
            "hits": []
        },
        "aggregations": {
            "characteristics": {
                "meta": {},
                "doc_count": 0,
                "ram": {
                    "meta": {},
                    "doc_count": 0,
                    "values": {
                        "doc_count": 0,
                        "all_values": {
                            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                            "buckets": []
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work in Elasticsearch 7.15 (based on your second sample):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "characteristics": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "characteristics"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ram": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "characteristics.name": "ram"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "characteristics.values"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "all_values": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "characteristics.values.value"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It's quite convoluted though so maybe it would make sense to create an additional "attribute values" index which would have a doc for each attribute value, containing also attribute name and product id/name? Then aggregation would get way simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, however, I tried with the agg traversal you provided and unfortunately it did not work.. I am getting missing definition for 'ram'

Comment: What Elasticsearch version do you use?

Comment: lastest version, 7.15

Comment: Weird: I've copy-pasted it from my Kibana console. Could you please share your index mapping?

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to help, here's a gist with the mapping:  https://gist.github.com/giannosdev/8e1bab851cad41959bfa01a9a71901b4

Comment: I've updated question with Document, Mapping, Aggregation traversal and response

Comment: You can't use `text` fields for bucket aggregations so use `keyword` subfields instead. Here's my mapping https://gist.github.com/ilvar/e06b6c24847c3b1ab721a59989834fbb query https://gist.github.com/ilvar/e2803bd75ac335dfebe1228b286d2267 and the result https://gist.github.com/ilvar/5d605f62df2c90752eae283bce2f9ee6

Comment: That was an issue after I've also noticed that my mapping was being mapped under "doc" which is an attribute being added by an automated part of my flow... so the mapping was wrong all along. Long gone are the days where I was trying to resolve this but atleast I can say I am better with ElasticSearch now...
I appreciate your help 100% and hope all the best for you!